# Refresh MasterView XML Parsed File - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have made an application for IPad in objective C. In this I am parsing an xml file and using it to display its contents in the MasterView(Split View App). However, the xml file is updated every now and then. How do I refresh the contents displayed in the Master View ??

I have parsed the xml file using NSXML Parser and currently I have used NSTimer to refresh the contents using "reloadData" commend every two seconds. It is NOT working. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first declare timer in .h file like bellow

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

and then use it in .m file like bellow syntax

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

here,if you want to repeats timer with viewWill Appear then above code declare in `viewWillAppear:` method..

hope,this help you....
:)

Comment: the timer is working but the view is not getting refreshed .. :(

Comment: ok then when you want to refresh the whole view just call viewWillAppear: method if more data are not loaded in it...